# Manipulate d3.js pack layout with HTML5 Range Input

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout, circle-pack

I have this http://jsfiddle.net/thechrisjordan/p4Fwm/11/, where I'm manipulating a d3 pack layout with an HTML5 slider. Everything is working as I would like except for how the nodes are ordered when updateVis() is called.

This code is pretty straight forward: I'm creating the layout, and then the slider emits an event which causes the layout to update.

What I'm hoping to achieve is this same behavior but to have the child nodes remain in their same general areas in the pack as they change size. As you can see, they reposition themselves here.

It looks like my issue is line **69** where `pack.nodes(data);` is called. I've dug into d3 source but can't figure out how to prevent this reordering (and it may very well not be possible...).

I suppose an alternative would be to try and squeeze the pack layout into a force layout.

I'm brand new to d3 and am grateful for any insight here.

Comment: This is unfortunately not supported by the pack layout -- you would have to modify the source (which may well be a non-trivial modification).

Comment: Thanks, @LarsKotthoff. According to meetamit it seems I overlooked the sort method available for pack layouts. That's what I get for digging into source and overlooking the docs :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood what you're asking to do, I'm pretty sure this is doable. [Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p4Fwm/12/); I added some RGB fun to help keep track of the circles.

This is done using the pack layout's `sort()` method, which ensures they're laid out in a persistent order. To achieve it, I had to assign an `index` value to each of the objects you declared (and the optional RGB color):

```
data.children.forEach(function(d, i) {
    d.index = i;
    d.fill = ['#c33','#3c3','#33c'][i];
});
```

Then it's a matter of using `index` to sort:

```
var pack = d3.layout.pack()
  .size([diameter - 4, diameter - 4])
  .sort(function(a,b) { return d3.ascending(a.index, b.index); }) // <--- this
  .value(function(d) { return d.size; });
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: Man, thanks a ton! I thought there might have been a way to do it, and I guess I overlooked this in the docs. I'm still coming up to speed with d3 so it's been a lot to digest. Thanks again; this was a huge help.